# Movable Type: Can't locate object method "new" via package "HTTP::Request

Tags: perl, movabletype

I am stuck on the last open source version of the blog software Movable Type before Movable Type went back to being a paid/professional offering only.

My host recently updated the Debian OS version and it apparently came with a more up-to-date version of Perl.

After the update, I am now getting the following error (specifically when Movable Type attempts to generate a Trackback, and I do need internal Trackbacks on my site):

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "HTTP::Request" at
> /home/super/www/www/cgi-bin/mt512/extlib/HTTP/Request.pm line 14.

The code on the line 14 in question is

> my $self = $class->SUPER::new($header, $content);

A larger snippet of the code from Request.pm, from the top of the file, is below.

I unfortunately don't know Perl.  But I am hoping someone might be able to tell me if there is a relatively easy way to address this.

```
package HTTP::Request;

require HTTP::Message;
@ISA = qw(HTTP::Message);
$VERSION = "5.827";

use strict;



sub new
{
my($class, $method, $uri, $header, $content) = @_;
my $self = $class->SUPER::new($header, $content);
$self->method($method);
$self->uri($uri);
$self;
}
```

**Update:** With help from Jay Allen, I was able to run mt-check.cgi

The check says that LWP::UserAgent is not installed:

[image: mt-check]

According to my site's Installed Perl 5 modules list, though, it is installed:

[image: LWP UserAgent]

I don't know if it's helpful, but there's also a CPAN::LWP::UserAgent:

[image: CPAN user agent]

Per Jay's original comments, I confirm that the MT cgi files begin with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

Here is the system information from mt-check:

> Operating system: linux
>
> Perl version: v5.24.1
>
> Perl include path:
>
> plugins/Textile/lib
>
> plugins/FormattedTextForTinyMCE/lib
>
> plugins/FormattedText/lib
>
> plugins/Minifier/lib
>
> plugins/MultiFileUploader/lib
>
> plugins/spamlookup/lib
>
> plugins/FacebookCommenters/extlib
>
> plugins/FacebookCommenters/lib
>
> plugins/Approval/lib
>
> plugins/CommentRating/lib
>
> plugins/WXRImporter/lib
>
> plugins/TinyMCE/lib
>
> plugins/mixiComment/lib
>
> plugins/CustomFieldsSearch/lib
>
> plugins/feeds-app-lite/lib
>
> plugins/StyleCatcher/lib
>
> plugins/WidgetManager/lib
>
> plugins/EmailRetitler/lib
>
> plugins/TypePadAntiSpam/lib
>
> plugins/NotifyWho/lib
>
> plugins/Profiler/lib
>
> addons/Community.pack/lib
>
> addons/Commercial.pack/lib
>
> extlib
>
> extlib
>
> lib
>
> /etc/perl
>
> /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1
>
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5
>
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24
>
> /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl-base .
>
> Web server: Apache
>
> (Probably) running under cgiwrap or suexec

Comment: Install the Perl LWP system package. You will probably need more dependencies. It looks like it didn't upgrade the system packages with Perl modules with the system. You can try to run it and search the Debian package website for the Perl module names from the errors to see which packages to install. You can also install the modules from cpan directly, but messing with the system Perl is not a good idea. Typically you'd have a Perl install for your production environment separately from the OS.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the LWP system package is already installed.  But thank you for your comment.

Comment: Where is that file you posted located? It might be the mt isn't using your system Perl. Check if you have another one.

Comment: The file is located in a subdirectory of the cgi-bin: /cgi-bin/mt/extlib/.  It doesn't seem like there is another instance of Perl.  I don't have direct access, but Perl is in /usr/bin/perl

Comment: Then maybe this whole extlib or parts of it are not visible to your Perl. Look at @INC and the PERL5LIB environment variables. There is a bunch of documentation online about how to get stuff there. I'm not familiar with mt so I don't know how it works.

Comment: Do you have shell access via SSH or telnet? If so, here are a few things to do to add information to your post: 1) Check that your CGI files (mt.cgi, mt-check.cgi, et al) start with `#!/usr/bin/perl` and not some other perl, 2) Run that perl  with the extended `-V` flag in order to find out not only the version but also the  built-in `@INC` (`/usr/bin/perl -V`), 3) Run `mt-check.cgi` to make sure that it is seeing the proper perl and `@INC` directories (you'll likely have to temporarily rename/move your `mt-config.cgi`). Add all of that output to your post minus any server identifying info

Comment: BTW re: #3 above: I meant run `mt-check.cgi` via your web browser not via the command line.

Comment: Also, any time you run into errors with Movable Type, you should enable `DebugMode` (i.e. put `DebugMode 3` in your `mt-config.cgi`) as it allows for more complete error messages.  Depending on the error, that will either be output to your web browser or into your webserver's error log. You may also want to check your webserver's error log anyway because there might be warnings there which might help uncover the problem.

Comment: I just saw that you said you didn't have direct access by which I suppose you mean shell access.  So, you can still do #1 and #3 above as well as the `DebugMode` suggestion.  Hopefully your webhost gives you web-based access to your webserver error logs but if not, we can get around that problem.

Comment: Nevermind all of my comments above for now.  See my answer below which is the likely issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46897080/255642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Movable Type includes a lot of non-compiled CPAN libraries in your `extlib` directory. The idea is that this makes it easier for people to run it who can't install modules.  Unfortunately, when you upgrade Perl but not Movable Type, those modules mask the proper and necessary ones that are either bundled with the new Perl library or installed by your web host. That is exactly the case with `LWP` and `HTTP:*`.

To solve this, you can **rename the following `extlib` files/directories**  using your FTP software:

- `HTTP/`
- `LWP/`
- `LWP.pm`

I usually just tack on `-MOVED` to the end.  Assuming this works, you can delete these files/directories entirely.

Additionally, there are other libraries which need the same treatment in some later version although I'm not sure which. It may be the one you're using:

- `JSON`
- `JSON.pm`
- `version/`
- `version.pm`
- `version.pod`

**UPDATE:** I forgot a few more from that list:

- `Net/HTTP/`
- `Net/HTTP.pm`
- `Net/HTTPS.pm`
- `Params/Validate.pm`
- `Params/ValidatePP.pm`
- `Params/ValidateXS.pm`
- `Params/Validate/`

And it also looks like Perl 5.24 [gave us at least one more module](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=105109) to rename or delete from extlib:

- `URI/`
- `URI.pm`

These last two are why LWP::UserAgent is throwing an error when you run `mt-check.cgi`.

Comment: After renaming all of these folders/files, I am now getting the same error at a different location: Saving Entry failed: Can't locate object method "new" via package "HTTP::Request" at lib/MT/Util.pm line 1407.   It's the same whether or not I rename the second list.  But I've updated the original post with the info from your initial comments.  It does seem that LWP::UserAgent is not being seen.  So it seems this is all on the right track.  Thank you so much for your help so far.

Comment: Awesome! I'm happy to help.